# inl instruction in __asm__

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, inline-assembly

Been going through the linux kernel code and I have seen this:

`__asm__("inl (%%dx)..."`

Been trying to look it up online but couldnt find any docs on this instruction.

Its supposed to be something related to I/O.

Comment: It is "IN" + "Long" as it is written in AT&T syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the [`IN` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/IN.html) with a 16-bit port argument (`%dx`) and a 32-bit destination value (`%eax`):

```
OpCode  Instruction  Op/En  64-Bit Mode     Compat/Leg Mode  Description
ED      IN EAX,DX    ZO     Valid           Valid            Input doubleword from I/O port in DX into EAX.
```

It reads a `DWORD` from the I/O address space.